OpenID Connect (oidc) .AspNetCore.Correlation cookie not found while login with another account
Implemented OpenID Connect authentication with Microsoft Entra ID in asp core 7 MVC and working fine though while switching account after logout getting below error:
2024-03-28T06:25:03.4772472-04:00 4000002b-0001-ee00-b63f-84710c7967bb [WRN] '".AspNetCore.Correlation.CXGr0OynmpPr_pBkyB_cWEUi2BISbbj_Jywsm-nfRKs"' cookie not found. (85986347)
2024-03-28T06:25:03.4805779-04:00 4000002b-0001-ee00-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. (48a46595)
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

Any help please ?
I tried setting cookie as below but then getting Correlation failed error.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
              {
                  builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
                  //options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                  options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
                  {

                      context.Response.Redirect(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:SSOAfterSignOutRedirectUrl"] ?? "/Account/AfterSignOut");
                      context.HandleResponse();

                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  };


                  options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;

                  options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;




              })

Also observed that correlation cookie not there after login either locally or production and error happening after logout and login again with another user

It is happening when deployed in IIS not locally

I deduce that you are trying to get the sign-out feature working well so that you could continue to sign in with another account in your application. Per my testing, we are not necessary to adding so much configurations.
I created a new .net 7 MVC application and choosing Microsoft Identity platform as the Authentication Type by VS 2022. Then I filled the appsettings.json with the AAD application information. Then my codes and configurations look like this.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
},

This makes me get the test result like below. By the way, most of the time, I would see that the sign out progress would stop at "close the browser" to make sure all user session information is cleared.



If we require to force to log out then redirect to specific page, I found a workaround provide by this answer

Thanks, It is happening when deployed in IIS not locally

thanks for your coming back. Do you mean that, your codes worked well when test locally within VS, but the issue occurred after you published it to IIS? If so, could you please let me know whether you changed any default configurations in IIS?

All settings are same
` "AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"TenantId": "-----------44b1---ff-",
"ClientId": "c--0-171c-4660-804b-751-----6f",
"CallbackPath": "/Account/SigninOidc",
} `

could you pls help confirm whether there's only one website inside the iis which hosting this problematic app? If not, could you pls stop other websites temporarily and test again? Pls test in private browser window.

Thanks for your response. There is separate application pool for this app and still same error after log in with another user after logout from first user
AspNetCore.Correlation.CXGr0OynmpPr_pBkyB_cWEUi2BISbbj_Jywsm-nfRKs"' cookie not found.
Also observed that after I empty browser cache it get works

then that means the issue is not resulted from other application pool influence, and clean browser cache helps solve the issue --> can we understand it as the cookie doesn't clearly or doesn't covered then causing the isue？

I can see correlation cookies are created fine when I login with first account and after logout when tries to login with another account then correlation cookies not get created until I use option "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"
